# Reconciling two different representations of Bell's inequality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality

I have a troubling question. The original Bell inequality:

$$|P(\vec{a},\vec{b}) - P(\vec{a},\vec{c})| - P(\vec{b},\vec{c}) \leq 1$$

is maximally violated at angles of 60 and 120 degrees. This is clear to me, because:

$$P_{xy} = -cos(\theta_x - \theta_y)$$

And naturally:

$$-cos(60) = -0.5, -cos(120) = 0.5$$

hence the inequality becomes:

$$1.5 \nleq 1$$

However, some literature, including [A simple proof of Bell’s inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5214) use the following variant of inequality:

$$P_{same}(A, B) + P_{same}(A, C) + P_{same}(B, C) \geq 1$$

Which they then proceed to prove as maximally violated at 60/120 degrees with:

$$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \ngeq 1$$

How do you arrive from the first to second conclusion? [Rieffel and Polak](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/quantum-computing) even explicitly use the following approach, without, unfortunately explaining the reasoning (at least not well enough to me):

$$cos^2{\theta} + cos^2{\phi} + cos^2{(\theta + \phi)} ≥ 1$$

The math works because squaring 0.5 three times will indeed give us $\frac{3}{4}$, but why are they doing this?

Answer (score 3):

**Where $P_{same}(A,B) + P_{same}(A,C) + P_{same}(B,C) \geq 1$ is coming from:**

This is explained in one of the references of ''A simple proof of Bell's inequality'', [lecture notes by Preskill, see Preskill 1-6, page 147](http://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/quantumcomputers/literature/). The argument goes as follows:

If you have a coin with three properties $A,B,C$ which can either be 0 or 1 (or just say you have three numbers $A,B,C$ which can each be either 0 or 1), two of them are always equal. For example (1,0,0) means $B=C$, (0,1,0) means $A=C$. They just cannot be all different because there are two choices (0 or 1) for three slots.

$P_{same}(A,B)= \bigg\{ \begin{matrix} 1 ,~(A=B) \\ 0,~ (A\neq B) \end{matrix}$ implies $P_{same}(A,B) + P_{same}(A,C) + P_{same}(B,C) \geq 1.$

(Maybe this was already clear. If yes, excuse the redundant explanation.)

**How to compute the l.h.s. for a Bell state:**

Coming back to the Bell experiment, the paper suggests three measurement directions $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $0^\circ, 60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$, respectively. They have the following eigenvectors $e_1$ and in direction of the measurement and $e_0$ perpendicular to it:
$$ |a_1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},~ |a_0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}~;~~ |b_1\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  \sqrt{3} \\ -1 \end{pmatrix},~ |b_0\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{3} \end{pmatrix}~;~~ |c_1\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  \sqrt{3} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},~ |c_0\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ -\sqrt{3} \end{pmatrix}. $$
Each eigenvector is given by $e_1(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}  \sin(2\theta) \\ \cos(2\theta) \end{pmatrix}$ (really just the direction of the measurement on the bloch sphere, i.e., with $2\theta$) for $\theta = 0, 60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$. The perpendicular one is hence $e_0(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}  \cos(2\theta) \\ -\sin(2\theta) \end{pmatrix}$.

The considered bell state is:
$$ |\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |00 \rangle + |11 \rangle )  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big[ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \Big]$$
In the "simple proof of Bell's inequality" it is shown in in eq. (3) that this entangled state corresponds to two entangled states with the same properties regarding $a, b$ and $c$. The probabilities $P_{same}(A,B)$ etc. are the chances that we measure $a_0$ in the first and $b_0$ in the second state, e.g.,
$$ | (\langle a_0 | \otimes \langle b_0| | \Phi^+ \rangle|^2 = 1/8,~ | (\langle a_1 | \otimes \langle b_1| | \Phi^+ \rangle|^2 = 1/8 \Rightarrow P_{same}(A,B) = 1/8 + 1/8 = 1/4.$$
These are also worked out in the paper below eq. (3).

I hope this clarifies where all this is coming from (and not making it more confusing).